# Calculate proportions per group

Tags: r

I have a dataset (B) with two variables class id (sg_id) and students school year (trs1jgs) as a factor that can be 3 or 4. What I want is a table showing the proportion of students from Grade 3 and Grade 4 per class. In addition, I need a variable or vector that contains the proportion of Grade 3 students per class in order to calculate the mean and sd of that proportion. How can I do this?
I tried:

```
Grade <- B %>%
  group_by(sg_id, trs1jgs) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  mutate(freq = n / sum(n))
```

This returns a tibble with 4 columns: sg_id, trs1jgs, n, freq. However if a class has only students from Grade 3, the table contains only one line and not two (second one indicating that 0 students were in Grade 4 or the other way around). Thus, I can not extract the n to calculate mean and sd. Is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
table(B)

        trs1jgs
sg_id    3 4
  class1 1 2
  class2 1 3
  class3 1 4
```

Used data:

```
set.seed(50)
B <- data.frame(sg_id = sample(c("class1", "class2", "class3"), 12, replace = T),
           trs1jgs = sample(c(3,4), 12, replace = T) %>% factor)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want add the relative frequencies to your calculations you will have to group by a different variable after counting, such that the shares are calculated using the correct number of observations from each corresponding group.

The following might work for you:

```
Grade <- B %>% 
group_by((sg_id, trs1jgs) %>%
summarise(n = n()) %>% 
group_by(sg_id) %>% 
mutate(freq = n/sum(n))
```

Comment: I tried your code but the resulting dataframe looks exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

I found a code which works:

```
Grade <- B %>%
  group_by(sg_id, trs1jgs) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = trs1jgs, values_from = n, values_fill = 0) %>%
  mutate(Total = `3` + `4`,
         Prop_3 = (`3` / Total) * 100,
         Prop_4 = (`4` / Total) * 100) %>%
  select(sg_id, Prop_3, Prop_4)
```